# Get IDs of parallel computing tasks with error

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, jobs

When I print a matlab (2011b or 2013a) parallel-computing-toolbox job using the console like this:

```
>> findResource.jobs(1)
ans =

Job ID 17 Information
=====================

              UserName : jgleixner
                 State : finished
            SubmitTime : Sat Aug 03 05:02:59 CEST 2013
             StartTime : Sat Aug 03 05:03:12 CEST 2013
      Running Duration : 0 days 3h 37m 9s
- Data Dependencies

      FileDependencies : {}
      PathDependencies : {}

- Associated Task(s)

       Number Pending  : 0
       Number Running  : 0
       Number Finished : 120
      TaskID of errors : [1x94 double]
```

ml shows an array of the IDs of tasks that threw errors. However, if this array is too long, the values are not printed (as in the example above).

How do I access this array programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is an instance of the `parallel.Job` class, so have a look at the [documentation here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/parallel.job.html).  You can get an array of all [`parallel.Task`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/parallel.task.html) objects by fetching the `Tasks` property, and they contain information about any errors which occurred.

Comment: so there is no one-liner?

Comment: As far as I can see, although I may have missed it, the array is not a property of the class.  I guess it must compute it from the `Task` array when displaying output.  So no.